# Pasting into Guake terminal starts the Android emulator! How do I stop this?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, terminal-emulator, oh-my-zsh, guake

(Using Ubuntu 17.10)
I don't know how this happened. I use `Guake terminal` and `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`, and also have had the Android emulator(along with the sdk etc.) installed for a long time. For some reason, one day, pasting into Guake using Ctrl-V, the mouse and context menu, or Ctrl-Shift-V, all started to

**a)** Open the Android emulator and then

**b)** Spit some emulator related garble onto the terminal, followed finally by the text I wanted to paste.

I can then close the emulator and use the pasted text. 
This, as you can imagine, became infuriating. 
So I just now deleted the entire folder of Android related stuff, the sdk, the ndk's, all tools etc. including the emulator. Now when I paste to Guake I see the line:

```
 bracketed-paste-magic:12: no such file or directory: /home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator
```

Followed by:

[image]

All I know about bracketed-paste-magic is that it is a part of zsh... I have never intentionally used this feature.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: `emulate` is a zsh builtin which is used in a lot of functions. Looks like it's being overridden by a function. What does `type emulate` say? Does your `.zshrc` define a function called `emulate` or does it include something related to the Android emulator?